# I just started learning Node.js with VS code, after i try to start it t get error:

Tags: node.js

I just started learning `Node.js` with VS code, after I try to start it get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

How can i fix this?
Here is some code. I'm trying to download some images from some pages but I haven't finished yet

````
const puppeteer = require('Puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const downloader = require('Image-downloader');

Function GetlargestImagesFromSrcset(SrcSet) {
    const SplitedSrcs = srcset.split(',');
    const ImgSrc = SplitedSrcs[SplitedSrcs.length - 1].split(' ')[0];
    return ImgSrc;
}

async function GetImageFromPage(Url) {
    const Browser = await puppeteer.Launch();
    const page = await brwoser.newpage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const ImageSrcSets = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const imgs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('Article img'));
        const srcSetAttribute = imgs.map(i => i.getAttribute('Srcset'));
        return srcSetAttribute;
    })

    const imgUrls = ImageSrcSets.map(srcSet => GetlargestImagesFromSrcset(SrcSet));
    await browser.Close();
    return imgUrls;
}

async Function main() {
        //
        if (!fs.existSync('./result')) {
            fs.mkdirSync('./result');
        }
        const images = await GetImageFromPage('')
        Console.log(images);
        Main();
    ```
````

Comment: What did you try? It is impossible for people to help given this info only

Comment: Hi! Can you please add some of the code that will help us find the error source?Seeing this current error it is impossible to know what is happening.

Comment: You probably have a syntax error in one of your modules and node.js encounters an error when trying to load that module.  We can't help without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: I'm trying to download some images from web

Comment: In what code do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

see the keywords and variable name you have used
**Function** is wrong it should be **function**
Similarly **Console** should be **console** 
the closing braces of main function is not present

```
const puppeteer = require('Puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const downloader = require('Image-downloader');

function GetlargestImagesFromSrcset(SrcSet) {
    const SplitedSrcs = SrcSet.split(',');
    const ImgSrc = SplitedSrcs[SplitedSrcs.length - 1].split(' ')[0];
    return ImgSrc;
}

async function GetImageFromPage(Url) {
    const Browser = await puppeteer.Launch();
    const page = await brwoser.newpage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const ImageSrcSets = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const imgs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('Article img'));
        const srcSetAttribute = imgs.map(i => i.getAttribute('Srcset'));
        return srcSetAttribute;
    })

    const imgUrls = ImageSrcSets.map(srcSet => GetlargestImagesFromSrcset(SrcSet));
    await browser.Close();
    return imgUrls;
}

async function main() {
        //
        if (!fs.existSync('./result')) {
            fs.mkdirSync('./result');
        }
        const images = await GetImageFromPage('')
        console.log(images);
}
        main();
```

Comment: Okay i will try